# Using an email reply as a decision split in a journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We are working on a journey and we'd want to do something like if a person replies to an email, he/she will exit the journey.  But if the person makes an engagement, he/she will continue with the journey. Is that even possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

You can set up triggered email as a Thank You email in Reply Mail Management for when the subscriber replies to the email. Then query that TriggeredSendCustomerKey in the [_Sent](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_sent.htm&type=5) data view to see if they were sent that message and update your Journey DE. Use that as a decision split in your journey.